# How to import "xmlns:app="http....pk/res-auto" in xml automatically? or How to creat a template xml which includes this "xmlns:app" scheme?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

As well known, ConstraintLayout is now a most popular and efficient layout on android development. But for using it's attributes, you gotta import "xmlns:app" first. It's very annoying when you need to creat many xml files with ConstraintLayout. How do I creat xml files with this scheme("xmlns:app") automatically? I need a template instead of importing it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is go to File -> New -> Edit File Templates.. -> Click + button -> paste your ConstraintLayout layout here -> Click ok. Done.
[image: Add custom xml]

To use it: Right Click -> New -> MyXML (your xml file name)
[image: use custom xml file]

Comment: Very nice, I will use your answer. But before that, May I ask you one more question that How do I sort "MyXML" to the top of the list?(The Java class is at the top position now, But I want to sort "MyXML" to the top).... Is there a way to make it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The best in my opinion is to use `Live Templates` in Android Studio. It lets you create code snippets and add them with matter of seconds into the code:

https://medium.com/google-developers/writing-more-code-by-writing-less-code-with-android-studio-live-templates-244f648d17c7

And here is the example with XML:

https://riggaroo.dev/create-live-templates-android-studio/

So what you can really do is put this:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in Android Studio -> Preferences -> Live Templates

[image]

Comment: Nguyễn Quang Thọ's answer is what I want, but I learned from your answer too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Go to Setting -> Menus and Toolbars -> Project view popup menu -> Change position of the From Template by press Alt + up (Alt + down), click ok to apply it

[image: arrange custom xml file]